# XML based Flash template acts different between web hosting services

Tags: xml, flash, templates, google-chrome, hosting

I've purchased a template which use XML with Flash. "Gallery" page of this template has a problem on Google Chrome at this site: http://www.acmimarlik.com.tr/test2/#/gallery

As you can see, thumbnail pictures do not hover. Tests for Firefox and IE are ok but only the Chrome can not view these thumbnails.

SAME code is (without any edits) uploaded to different sites, too, without any problems, thumbs are ok, hover works:
http://www.ikikalem.com/test2/#/gallery and http://acik.org/black2/#/gallery

What can be the problem? Is it about my hosting service or what?

Any helps are needed.

Regards,

Ender

Comment: What exactly do you mean by hover? I looked through each link in both chrome and FF and they all exhibit identical behavior.

Comment: The first [link](http://www.acmimarlik.com.tr/test2/#/gallery) is the failed one. Only the rightmost column reacts to mouse hover.